# Printing a dot in Perl won't come on the screen till I print something else

Tags: perl

This sounds crazy but nothing shows up on the screen when I use the line `printf(".")` until I print something else.  When I print out other info, from a simple line return to actual data all the backed up dots print out.  If I use `printf(".\n")` then it works fine.

Am doing this on an Ubuntu system if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `printf` when there are no format specifiers. This isn't C, and `print` is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a buffering issue. Try setting autoflush: `$| = 1`;

```
{
    $| = 1;
    print ".";
}
sleep 1 for 1..5;
```

`STDOUT` is line-buffered, so `print ".\n"` works fine

More information: [Suffering from buffering?](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)

Another useful answer: [*Can you force-flush output in Perl?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812618/can-you-force-flush-output-in-perl)

Comment: Or `STDOUT->autoflush(1);`.

Comment: Why `sleep 1 for 1..5` instead of `sleep 5`?

Comment: perldoc -f sleep


...On some older systems, it may sleep up to a full second less than what you requested, depending on how it counts seconds.

Comment: So you prefer to sleep for 0 to 5 seconds over sleeping for 4 to 5 seconds?

Comment: You can add validation and sleep more or skip extra seconds ;)
P.S. Okay, next time I will use sleep(5)

Answer (score 3):

Like other have said, it is a buffering issue. In recent enough versions of Perl you can do:

```
 use IO::Handle
 STDOUT->autoflush()
```

I think this is cleaner than using the `$|` variable, even if it will work in the same way.

The `use IO::Handle` is needed to attach the `autoflush` method to any future handle. And `autoflush` has its quirks in the sense that without passing a value it assumes `1` as written in the `perlvar` man page:

> The methods each take an optional EXPR, which, if supplied, specifies the new value for the "IO::Handle" attribute in question.  If not supplied, most methods do nothing to the current value--except for "autoflush()", which will assume a 1 for you, just to be different.